# Cannot Debug Xamarin Forms App on Android O

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mono, adb

Does anybody have experience with debugging their Xamarin Forms app on an external Android O device?

Debugging with the emulator is fine (as is Release mode with my external device), but debugging on my physical device causes the following error:

```
Couldn't connect to logcat, GetProcessId returned: 0
```

I have tested adb and that works fine. I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: [File a bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Android)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a confirmed bug :

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56740